# Out of memory error when reading and parsing a .ged file into a sqlite database

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, memory-management, out-of-memory, gedcom

I have written the following program that reads and parses a .ged file (genealogy data) and stores it in an SQLite database. The program works, however when a large file is loaded, I get an "out of memory exception". I'm new to Visual Basic, but it appears that every object that is created is stored in memory until the program ends, as memory usage increases up to 4 gigs as the program runs.

I've searched all over but cannot find a solution. Help!

I have a similar Family and Child class and subs in the server class for each.

Person Class:

```
Public Class Person

Public Property ID As String
Public Property personID As String
Public Property surName As String
Public Property givenName As String
Public Property sex As String
Public Property birthDate As String
Public Property birthYear As String
Public Property birthPlace As String
Public Property deathDate As String
Public Property deathYear As String
Public Property deathPlace As String
Public Property famC As String

End Class
```

Server:

```
Public Sub AddPerson(p As Person)
    Dim addPersonquery As String = "INSERT INTO Person(
                                         ID,
                                         PersonID,
                                         SurName,
                                         GivenName,
                                         Sex,
                                         BirthDate,
                                         BirthPlace,
                                         DeathDate,
                                         DeathPlace,
                                         FamC)
                                        VALUES(
                                        @ID,
                                        @pid,
                                        @sn,
                                        @gn,
                                        @se,
                                        @bd,
                                        @bP,
                                        @dd,
                                        @dp,
                                        @fc);"
    Using SqlConn As New SQLiteConnection(AMconnectionString)
        Dim cmd As New SQLiteCommand(addPersonquery, SqlConn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", p.ID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid", p.personID)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sn", p.surName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gn", p.givenName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@se", p.sex)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bd", p.birthDate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bp", p.birthPlace)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dd", p.deathDate)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dp", p.deathPlace)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fc", p.famC)
        SqlConn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Main Program:

```
Option Strict On
Public Class GedcomParser
Dim AdamMarsServer As New Server()
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    AdamMarsServer.CreateDatabase()
    Gedcomreader()
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Gedcomreader()
    Dim ofdbox As New OpenFileDialog()
    ofdbox.Title = "Select Your FTM Gedcom file"
    ofdbox.Filter = "gedcom Files|*.ged"
    ofdbox.InitialDirectory = (My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments)
    ofdbox.ShowDialog()
    Dim fileReader As System.IO.StreamReader
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileReader(ofdbox.FileName)
    Dim stringReader As String
    Dim strRecData As String
    Dim strPlaceHolder As String
    Dim blnIndividual As Boolean
    Dim blnFamily As Boolean

    stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
    Do While Not stringReader = ""
        stringReader = fileReader.ReadLine()
        strPlaceHolder = stringReader
        If Strings.Left(strPlaceHolder, 1) = "0" Then
            If Len(strRecData) <> 0 Then
                If blnFamily Or blnIndividual Then
                    ParseRecord(strRecData)
                    'numpeople.Text = ProgressBar2.Value.ToString()
                    'numfam.Text = ProgressBar3.Value.ToString()
                    strRecData = ""
                    blnFamily = False
                    blnIndividual = False
                End If
            End If
            Select Case Strings.Right(strPlaceHolder, 3)
                Case "NDI"
                    blnIndividual = True
                    blnFamily = False
                    strRecData = "IND " & strPlaceHolder
                    'ProgressBar2.Increment(1)
                Case "FAM"
                    blnFamily = True
                    blnIndividual = False
                    strRecData = "FAM " & strPlaceHolder
                    'ProgressBar3.Increment(1)
            End Select

        Else
            If blnIndividual Or blnFamily Then
                strRecData = strRecData & vbCr & strPlaceHolder
            End If
        End If
    Loop
    fileReader.Close()
    MessageBox.Show("Done")
End Sub

Private Sub ParseRecord(strRecord As String)

    Dim childs As New child()
    Dim persons As New Person()
    Dim mfamily As New Family()
    Dim intPosition As Integer = 6
    Dim strData As String
    Dim strSubType As String

    Select Case Strings.Left(strRecord, 3)
        Case "IND"
            Do While intPosition <> 0
                intPosition = 1
                intPosition = InStr(intPosition, strRecord, Chr(13))

                If intPosition = 0 And Len(strRecord) > 0 Then
                    strData = strRecord
                Else
                    strData = Strings.Left(strRecord, intPosition)
                End If
                strRecord = Strings.Right(strRecord, Len(strRecord) - intPosition)

                If String.Compare(strData, 0, "IND", 0, 3) = 0 Then
                    persons.personID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                               InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)

                    childs.PersonID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                               InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                Else

                    Select Case Strings.Left(strData, 1)
                        Case "1"
                            Select Case Mid(strData, 3, 4)
                                Case "NAME"
                                    If Len(strData) = 7 Then
                                        persons.surName = ""
                                        persons.givenName = ""
                                    Else

                                        persons.surName = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "/") + 1,
                                                              InStrRev(strData, "/") - InStr(1, strData, "/") - 1)
                                        Dim givName = Split(strData, "/")(0)
                                        persons.givenName = givName.Remove(0, 7)
                                    End If
                                Case "BIRT"
                                    strSubType = "BIRTH"
                                Case "DEAT"
                                    strSubType = "DEATH"
                                Case "FAMC"
                                    persons.famC = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                                           InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                                    childs.familyID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                                           InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                                Case "SEX "
                                    persons.sex = Mid(strData, 7, 1)
                                Case Else

                            End Select

                        Case "2"
                            Select Case strSubType
                                Case "BIRTH"
                                    If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                        persons.birthDate = GetGenData(strData)
                                    ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                        persons.birthPlace = GetGenData(strData)
                                    End If
                                Case "DEATH"
                                    If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                        persons.deathDate = GetGenData(strData)
                                    ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                        persons.deathPlace = GetGenData(strData)
                                    End If
                                Case Else
                            End Select
                    End Select
                End If
            Loop

            AdamMarsServer.AddPerson(persons)
            AdamMarsServer.Addchild(childs)
        Case "FAM"

            Do While intPosition <> 0
                intPosition = 1
                intPosition = InStr(intPosition, strRecord, Chr(13))
                If intPosition = 0 And Len(strRecord) > 0 Then
                    strData = strRecord
                Else
                    strData = Strings.Left(strRecord, intPosition)
                End If
                strRecord = Strings.Right(strRecord, Len(strRecord) - intPosition)
                If String.Compare(strData, 0, "FAM", 0, 3) = 0 Then
                    mfamily.FamilyID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                               InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                Else
                    Select Case Strings.Left(strData, 1)
                        Case "1"
                            Select Case Mid(strData, 3, 4)
                                Case "HUSB"
                                    mfamily.HusbandID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                                                InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                                Case "WIFE"
                                    mfamily.WifeID = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1,
                                                             InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
                                Case "MARR"
                                    strSubType = "Marriage"
                                Case Else
                            End Select
                        Case "2"
                            Select Case strSubType
                                Case "Marriage"
                                    If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                        mfamily.MarriageDate = GetGenData(strData)
                                    ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                        mfamily.MarriagePlace = GetGenData(strData)
                                    End If
                                Case Else
                            End Select
                    End Select
                End If
            Loop
            AdamMarsServer.AddFamily(mfamily)

    End Select

End Sub

Function GetGEDNumber(GED As String) As String
    GetGEDNumber = Mid(GED, InStr(1, GED, "@") + 1, InStrRev(GED, "@") - InStr(1, GED, "@") - 1)
End Function

Function GetGenData(Data As String) As String
    GetGenData = Replace(Replace(Strings.Right(Data, Len(Data) - 7), Chr(13), ""), Chr(10), "")
End Function
```

End Class

This was addapted from this VBA Program:

```
Sub ImportGED(strFullFileName As String)
Dim fso As New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim filGED As Scripting.File
Dim txsGED As Scripting.TextStream
Dim strLine As String
Dim strRecData As String
Dim strPlaceHolder As String
Dim blnIndividual As Boolean
Dim blnFamily As Boolean
Dim strSubType As String

Screen.MousePointer = ccHourglass
Set filGED = fso.GetFile(strFullFileName)
Set txsGED = filGED.OpenAsTextStream(ForReading, TristateUseDefault)

Do While Not txsGED.AtEndOfStream
If Form_GetGEDFile.ProgressBar2.Value < 25 Then
    Form_GetGEDFile.ProgressBar2.Value = Form_GetGEDFile.ProgressBar2.Value + 1
Else
    Form_GetGEDFile.ProgressBar2.Value = 1
End If
Form_GetGEDFile.Repaint
Form_GetGEDFile.Refresh

strPlaceHolder = txsGED.ReadLine
If Left(strPlaceHolder, 1) = "0" Then

    If Len(strRecData) <> 0 Then
        If blnFamily Or blnIndividual Then
            ParseRecord strRecData
            strRecData = ""
            blnFamily = False
            blnIndividual = False
        End If
    End If

    Select Case Right(strPlaceHolder, 3)
        Case "NDI"
            blnIndividual = True
            blnFamily = False
            strRecData = "IND " & strPlaceHolder
        Case "FAM"
            blnFamily = True
            blnIndividual = False
            strRecData = "FAM " & strPlaceHolder
    End Select

Else
    If blnIndividual Or blnFamily Then
        strRecData = strRecData & vbCr & strPlaceHolder
    End If
End If
Loop
Form_GetGEDFile.ProgressBar2.Value = 25
txsGED.Close
Screen.MousePointer = ccDefault

End Sub

Sub ParseRecord(strRecord As String)
Dim conGen As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rstData As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim rstQuery As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim intPosition As Integer
Dim blnInSub As Boolean
Dim strData As String

intPosition = 1
conGen.Open Application.CurrentProject.BaseConnectionString


Select Case Left(strRecord, 3)
Case "IND"
    rstData.Open "Select * FROM Individuals", conGen, adOpenKeyset, adLockPessimistic
    rstData.AddNew
    Do While intPosition <> 0
        intPosition = 1
        intPosition = InStr(intPosition, strRecord, Chr(13))

        If intPosition = 0 And Len(strRecord) > 0 Then
            strData = strRecord
        Else
            strData = Left(strRecord, intPosition)
        End If
        strRecord = Right(strRecord, Len(strRecord) - intPosition)

        If Left(strData, 3) = "IND" Then
            rstData![GED ID] = Mid(strData, InStr(1, strData, "@") + 1, InStrRev(strData, "@") - InStr(1, strData, "@") - 1)
        Else
            Select Case Left(strData, 1)
                Case 1
                    Select Case Mid(strData, 3, 4)
                        Case "NAME"
                            rstData![Full Name] = Replace(GetGenData(strData), "/", "")
                            strSubType = "NAME"
                        Case "BIRT"
                            strSubType = "BIRTH"
                        Case "DEAT"
                            strSubType = "DEATH"
                        Case "FAMC"
                            rstData!Parents = GetGEDNumber(strData)
                        Case "SEX "
                            rstData!Sex = Mid(strData, 7, 1)
                    End Select
                Case 2
                    Select Case strSubType
                        Case "Name"
                            If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "GIVN" Then
                                rstData![Given Name] = GetGenData(strData)
                            ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "SURN" Then
                                rstData!Surname = GetGenData(strData)
                            End If
                        Case "BIRTH"
                            If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                rstData![Birth Date] = GetGenData(strData)
                            ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                rstData![Birth Location] = GetGenData(strData)
                            End If
                        Case "DEATH"
                            If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                rstData![Death Date] = GetGenData(strData)
                            ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                rstData![Death Location] = GetGenData(strData)
                            End If
                    End Select
            End Select
        End If
    Loop
    rstData.Update

Case "FAM"
    rstData.Open "Families", conGen, adOpenDynamic, adLockPessimistic
    rstData.AddNew
    Do While intPosition <> 0
        intPosition = 1
        intPosition = InStr(intPosition, strRecord, Chr(13))
        If intPosition = 0 And Len(strRecord) > 0 Then
            strData = strRecord
        Else
            strData = Left(strRecord, intPosition)
        End If
        strRecord = Right(strRecord, Len(strRecord) - intPosition)
        If Left(strData, 3) = "FAM" Then
            rstData![GED Family ID] = GetGEDNumber(strData)
        Else
            Select Case Left(strData, 1)
                Case 1
                    Select Case Mid(strData, 3, 4)
                        Case "HUSB"
                            rstQuery.Open "Select ID, [GED ID] FROM Individuals Where [GED ID]='" & GetGEDNumber(strData) & "'", conGen, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                            rstData![Father ID] = rstQuery!ID
                            rstQuery.Close
                        Case "WIFE"
                            rstQuery.Open "Select ID, [GED ID] FROM Individuals Where [GED ID]='" & GetGEDNumber(strData) & "'", conGen, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
                            rstData![Mother ID] = rstQuery!ID
                            rstQuery.Close
                        Case "MARR"
                            strSubType = "Marriage"
                    End Select
                Case 2
                    Select Case strSubType
                        Case "Marriage"
                            If Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "DATE" Then
                                rstData![Marriage Date] = GetGenData(strData)
                            ElseIf Mid(strData, 3, 4) = "PLAC" Then
                                rstData![Marriage Location] = GetGenData(strData)
                            End If
                    End Select
            End Select
        End If
    Loop
    rstData.Update

End Select
rstData.Close
Set rstData = Nothing
conGen.Close
Set conGen = Nothing
End Sub

Function GetGEDNumber(GED As String) As String
GetGEDNumber = Mid(GED, InStr(1, GED, "@") + 1, InStrRev(GED, "@") - InStr(1, 
GED, "@") - 1)
End Function

Function GetGenData(Data As String) As String
GetGenData = Replace(Replace(Right(Data, Len(Data) - 7), Chr(13), ""), 
Chr(10), "")
End Function
```

Am I missing this part in my code? If so, what do I need to replace it with?

```
rstData.Close
Set rstData = Nothing
conGen.Close
Set conGen = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory problems can be the result of not using `Using...End Using`. Variables in .net are garbage collected. This is managed code - read managed memory. Problems arise when an object uses unmanaged resources. To clean up these resources these objects implement `IDisposable` so they will have a `Dispose()` method. If we fail to call the `Dispose()` method than the unmanaged resources can pile up and cause "Out of Memory". A simple way to handle this is to use `Using...End Using`.

> Because of this, the Using block guarantees disposal of the
>   resources, no matter how you exit the block. This is true even in the
>   case of an unhandled exception, except SO Exception

(from ms docs)

You place the Using in place of the Dim statement.

```
Using cn as New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
```

Then, when your are finished using the connection,...

```
End Using
```

One caveat, this is a code block and anything declared inside it will not be visible outside. Declare and initialize any variables that you need before the block.